# Chain completation sync and async

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a list of completables that by default I run them one after one with concat/andThen operators.
Sometimes I want some part of the completables to run in parallel and after everything complete continue to the next completable in the list.
I tried to achieve that with this code:

```
    var completable =
            getAsyncCompletables()?.let {
                it
            } ?: run {
                completables.removeAt(0).getCompletable()
            }
        while (completables.isNotEmpty()) {
            val nextCompletable = getAsyncCompletables()?.let {
                it
            } ?: run {
                completables.removeAt(0).getCompletable()
            }
            completable = nextCompletable.startWith(completable)
        }
        completable
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
```

I use this code to detect the async completables:

```
 private fun getAsyncCompletables(): Completable? {
    if (completables.size < 2 || !completables[1].async) {
        return null
    }
    var completable = completables.removeAt(0).getCompletable()
    while (completables.isNotEmpty() && completables[0].async) {
        completable = completable.mergeWith(completables.removeAt(0).getCompletable())
    }
    return completable
}
```

All works fine, except one thing, the last completable not triggered althought I used "startWith".
I also tried "concatWith" and "andThen",but same result.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to answer without seeing more of your code, specifically what `async` does and what the data structure is for `completables`. However, the answer you are looking for is most likely similar regardless of these values. You will probably want to use `Completable.merge(...)` or `Completable.mergeArray(...)`.

As per the documentation:

```java
 /**
  * Returns a Completable instance that subscribes to all sources at once and
  * completes only when all source Completables complete or one of them emits an error.
  * ...
  */
```

In order to achieve the parallel execution, you will need to call `subscribeOn` each of your Completables in the list/array/set with a new thread. This can be done with `Schedulers.newThread()` or from a shared pool like `Schedulers.io()`.

I ran a test just to be sure. Here is the code.

```java
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...

    val completeOne = Completable.fromAction {
        Timber.d("Completable #1 running on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    val completeTwo = Completable.fromAction {
        Timber.d("Completable #2 running on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    val completeThree = Completable.fromAction {
        Timber.d("Completable #3 running on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    val completables = listOf(completeOne, completeTwo, completeThree).map { CompletableWrapper(it) }
    val asyncCompletables = completables
        .asSequence()
        .filter { it.async }
        .map { it.getCompletable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }
        .toList()

    Completable.merge(asyncCompletables)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            Timber.i("Completed all completables")
        }, Timber::e)
}

class CompletableWrapper(
    private val completable: Completable,
    val async: Boolean = true
) {
    fun getCompletable() = completable
}
```

And here is the output.

```bsh
D/MainActivity$onCreate$completeThree: Completable #3 running on RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
D/MainActivity$onCreate$completeTwo: Completable #2 running on RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
D/MainActivity$onCreate$completeOne: Completable #1 running on RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
I/MainActivity$onCreate: Completed all completables
```

As you can see, it runs each completable on a new thread from the pool and only calls completed all after each completable has finished.

[See here for the documentation on Completable.merge/mergeArray](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#mergeArray-io.reactivex.CompletableSource...-).